# How can I reshape polygon without change line lengths

Tags: javascript, polygon

I can reshape polygon with mouse by using code in snippet. After drawing polygon, users can change shape by moving points. But I want to modify shape without changing line lengths. The points will change as possible but length of the lines will remain the same.

How can I do this?

```js
var canvas, ctx;
var canvasIsMouseDown = false;
var radius = 6;
var pointIndex = -1;

var points = [
    { x: 10, y: 10 },
    { x: 100, y: 50 },
    { x: 150, y: 100 },
    { x: 60, y: 110 },
    { x: 30, y: 160 }
];
function start() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("cnPolygon");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", canvasMouseMove);
    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", canvasMouseDown);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", canvasMouseUp);
    draw();
}
function canvasMouseMove(ev) {
if (!canvasIsMouseDown || pointIndex === -1) return;
    points[pointIndex].x = ev.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    points[pointIndex].y = ev.pageY - this.offsetTop;
    draw();
}
function canvasMouseDown(ev) {
    canvasIsMouseDown = true;
    var x = ev.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    var y = ev.pageY - this.offsetTop;
    pointIndex = -1;
    var dist;
    for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x - points[i].x), 2) + Math.pow((y - points[i].y), 2));
        if (dist <= radius) {
            pointIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }
}
function canvasMouseUp(ev) {
        canvasIsMouseDown = false;
}
function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);
    for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        ctx.lineTo(points[i].x, points[i].y);
    }
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
    for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(points[i].x, points[i].y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", start);
```

```html
<canvas id="cnPolygon" width="200" height="200" style="border:solid 1px silver"></canvas>
```

Comment: Do you mean line width or line length? You have used both these phrases in your question. When you- say line width, I understand it as line thickness whereas line length is the distance between two points.

Comment: I meant line length. I corrected text. Thanks.

Comment: That is an interesting question. In some polygons it is not possible to move a single point without changing the length of the lines e.g, consider a triangle. In others such as a square you could move two points as a pair at the same time. I would approach this by using a rigid body simulator such as http://brm.io/matter-js/

Comment: matterjs looks impresive !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this

```js
var canvas, ctx;
var canvasIsMouseDown = false;
var radius = 3;
var pointIndex = -1;
var points = [
    { x: 10, y: 10 },
    { x: 100, y: 50 },
    { x: 150, y: 100 },
    { x: 60, y: 110 },
    { x: 30, y: 160 }
];

// PHYSICS START ----------------
var stiffness = 0.25 // defines how elastic the contrainst should be
var oscillations = 10 // defines how many iterations should be made, more iterations mean higher precision

function getAngle(x1,y1,x2,y2){
 return Math.atan2(y2-y1,x2-x1) + Math.PI/2
}
function getConstraintPos(tx,ty,ox,oy,dist){
 var rot = getAngle(tx,ty,ox,oy)
 var x = tx+Math.sin(rot)*dist
 var y = ty-Math.cos(rot)*dist
 return [x,y]
}
function applyContraintForce(point,pos){
 point.x += (pos[0] - point.x)*stiffness
    point.y += (pos[1] - point.y)*stiffness
}
function defineDistances(){
 for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
  var next_point = points[(i+1)%points.length]
  points[i].distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((next_point.x - points[i].x), 2) + Math.pow((next_point.y - points[i].y), 2))
 }
}
function updateContraints(){
 // forward pass
 for (var i=0;i<points.length;i++) 
    {
       if(i==pointIndex) continue
        var j = (+i+1)%points.length
        var pos = getConstraintPos(points[j].x,points[j].y,points[i].x,points[i].y,points[i].distance)
        applyContraintForce(points[i],pos)
    }
    //backward pass
    for (var i=points.length-1;i>=0;i--) 
    {
       if(i==pointIndex) continue
        var j = (i-1)
        j = j<0 ? points.length+j : j
        var pos = getConstraintPos(points[j].x,points[j].y,points[i].x,points[i].y,points[j].distance)
        applyContraintForce(points[i],pos)
    }
}
// PHYSICS END ----------------



function start() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("cnPolygon");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", canvasMouseMove);
    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", canvasMouseDown);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", canvasMouseUp);
    defineDistances()
    draw();
}
function canvasMouseMove(ev) {
    if (!canvasIsMouseDown || pointIndex === -1) return;
    points[pointIndex].x = ev.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    points[pointIndex].y = ev.pageY - this.offsetTop;
    for(var i=0;i<oscillations;i++){
     updateContraints()
    }
    draw();
}
function canvasMouseDown(ev) {
    canvasIsMouseDown = true;
    var x = ev.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    var y = ev.pageY - this.offsetTop;
    pointIndex = -1;
    var dist;
    for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        dist = Math.abs(Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x - points[i].x), 2) + Math.pow((y - points[i].y), 2)));
        if (dist <= radius) {
            pointIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }
}
function canvasMouseUp(ev) {
    canvasIsMouseDown = false;
}
function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);
    for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        ctx.lineTo(points[i].x, points[i].y);
    }
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
    for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(points[i].x, points[i].y, radius * 2, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", start);
```

```html
<canvas id="cnPolygon" width="500" height="300" style="border:solid 1px silver"></canvas>
```

What this does is calculate the angle between two given points and applies a force based on that angle and the distance delta. The force applied is multiplied by the `stiffness`.

This has to be done forwards *(point A -> point B)* and backwards *(point A <- point B)* in order to account for the differences between the last to first point in the chain.

**NOTE** this is not 100% accurate. The accuracy can be increased by the iterations count, but as @bhspencer already pointed out, there are cases where this is impossible, simply because of geometry.

Comment: That's a good answer. Thanks. It may only be necessary to make some changes to fit the project. I'm not sure whether it is necessary or not, but I may need a situation where only the positions of the drifting and neighboring points change as much as possible.